# How to get name of the channel in other's chat group in telegram bot python?

Tags: python, bots, admin, aiogram

I'am trying to get the name of the channel that sending message into other channel's chat. For example: I have channel named Cat and Cat chat; also I have a channel Dog. I've send the message using Dog into Cat chat and I wanna to get name Dog into variable.
I've tried `message.from_user.username` and `message.from_user.first_name` but it printed Channel_bot and Channel.
[There is example of other channel commenting in my chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcK8X.png)

So nickname "gdfgd" should be saved in variable. Is there any method that doing it? I'm using python and aiogram.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found method `message.sender_chat.title` that prints what i wanted!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).